# Getting text Fade In / Out when a certain DIV class is clicked on. Then hiding the new DIV after a requested time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing an ARG website. I'm building this to look like it had a backend, but it is no longer connected and only snapshots of the website pages exist. For hours I was trying to look into displaying an error message when you click any of my Div's with the class name "email_nav". I wanted this to work purely through CSS but couldn't figure it out. I decided to keep looking and I saw a few things that worked, and I was able to cobble together a result that flashes red and white to show an error when clicking on "Reply", "Reply All", "Forward" and "Delete". I'm being told this was the wrong way to perform this in the code I answered myself below with my final result but it's what I have working currently. Any help with cleaning up the code would be very helpful.

[image: the red error should flash red and then go transparent.]

Comment: This is not how Q&A works. Both the question and the answer have to match the quality standards; see [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/215552)

Comment: [ask] describes, with great detail, what is expected of questions. If you follow those guidelines, you are considerably less prone to getting downvotes. For instance, this question lacks any evidence of research other than the phrase "I found bits and parts".

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:** Both JavaScript files must be placed below the css and html for the code to work properly.
Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vLhxzgr/). Enjoy :)

HTML

```
<div class="email_nav" style="width: 50px;">Identify</div>
<div class="hide" id="error_text">Text Appears</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide {display: none;}
#error_text {animation: fadeIn 3s; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; background: #F00;}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 1;}
  40% {opacity: 0;}
  60% {opacity: 1;}
  80% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".email_nav").click(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#error_text").removeClass("hide");
  }, 0);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#error_text").addClass("hide");
  }, 3000);
});
```

jQuery Cloudflare API (Required)

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Without JQuery**

```
const n = document.querySelector(".email_nav");
const t = document.getElementById("error_text");

n.addEventListener("click", () => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      t.classList.remove("hide");
   }, 0);
   setTimeout(() => {
      t.classList.add("hide");
   }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Omg. Why did you use jq here? )

Comment: @AndreiFedorov It was the best I could come up with working with what I know. What would you have done different?

Comment: Probably would have used a version more recent that 2.1.3... Also, you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to get an experience close to jsFiddle, and people won't have to go to another site to see it work.

Comment: @AdamTourgeman For such a simple function, you pull hundreds of kilobytes of someone else's js code into the project

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the info. I appreciate it. I actually do not understand the differences between the different numbers. I assume them to be different generations so are things backwards compatible if I use newer ones?

Comment: @AndreiFedorov I understand that its wrong, may I ask what you would do? Like how would you write it in pure JavaScript?

Comment: @AndreiFedorov and HereticMonkey I can say that I am embarrassed. Before this post I always assumed that JavaScript was older than jQuery. I believed that I have been trying to mix JavaScript and jQuery interchangeably for years now as I never really thought to look into them. I was never sure what the jQuery script links were for, but I see now what they do. I feel dumb, and a little humbled. I am very sorry for assuming I knew what I was speaking about.

Comment: @AdamTourgeman Thank you for your reaction. This attitude is very valuable. 